# Changing the app Display Name loses translations?

Tags: facebook, internationalization, translation

I have an app with the display name: "ABC"

[image]

The entire app was translated with facebook i18n and it works:

> "Steve **bought** a car on **ABC**" -> "Steve comprou um carro no
>   ABC

But what is happening is that when I change the app to "ABCDEF" the feed messages does not come with translation anymore. Instead only with the default language english.

One thing I noticed is that in the translations admin ui, the token with the app name is with the old one, but it is supposed to work with the app Namespace at least.

[image]

Thanks!